# .Net setting and getting a Dictionary Property

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Below is a simple class that allows for setting `HighTemps` and `LowTemps`. There is also a read only property `TempRange` that uses a loop in its' `getter` to calculate. Is there a more elegant way to do this other than the loop? Given that TempRange will always be derived from `HighTemps` and `LowTemps` and that all three will basically have 7 items with an index, is there a better way to do this without a loop to set the value of `TempRange`?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public class Weather{
      public Weather(Dictionary<int,int> highTemps,Dictionary<int,int> lowTemps,Dictionary<int,int> tempRange){
        HighTemps = highTemps;
        LowTemps = lowTemps;
      }
      public Dictionary<int,int> HighTemps {get;set;}
      public Dictionary<int,int> LowTemps {get;set;}
      public Dictionary<int,int> TempRange{
        get{
            Dictionary<int,int> result = new Dictionary<int,int>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> pair in HighTemps)
            {
                result.Add(pair.Key,pair.Value - LowTemps[pair.Key]);
            }           
            return result;
        }
      }     
    }
    public static void Main(){      
        Weather temps = new Weather(new Dictionary<int,int>(),new Dictionary<int,int>(),new Dictionary<int,int>());
        //add day of week and temp
        temps.HighTemps.Add(1, 84);
        temps.HighTemps.Add(2, 86);
        temps.HighTemps.Add(3, 81);
        temps.HighTemps.Add(4, 82);
        temps.HighTemps.Add(5, 82);
        temps.HighTemps.Add(6, 83);
        temps.HighTemps.Add(7, 84);

        temps.LowTemps.Add(1, 65);
        temps.LowTemps.Add(2, 66);
        temps.LowTemps.Add(3, 71);
        temps.LowTemps.Add(4, 60);
        temps.LowTemps.Add(5, 64);
        temps.LowTemps.Add(6, 69);
        temps.LowTemps.Add(7, 70);      


        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> pair in temps.TempRange)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The range for Day {0} of the week was {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
}

//Output:
The range for Day 1 of the week was 19
The range for Day 2 of the week was 20
The range for Day 3 of the week was 10
The range for Day 4 of the week was 22
The range for Day 5 of the week was 18
The range for Day 6 of the week was 14
The range for Day 7 of the week was 14
```

Comment: Why not create a new type `class TempRangeInDay { public int High {get;set;} public int Low {get;set;} public DateTime Date {get; set;} }`. Then all your data is together in a high cohesive class. Then you create a list of these (or a lookup if needed using `HashSet<T>`, just don't forget to override the Equals/HashCode members.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a better way to do it than a loop.

Small things:

- The constructor takes 3 param, the 3rd one is useless, remove it.
- I think all your data could be store in a simple List of `WeatherDay`. Something like:

```
public class WeatherDay {
    public int Min;
    public int Max;
    public int Range => Max - Min;
}
```

Comment: How would you iterate each instance of the day? Put each instance in a List?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use Linq's toDictionary? https://www.dotnetperls.com/todictionary

```
public Dictionary<int, int> TempRange
{
    get 
    {
        return HighTemps.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value - LowTemps[v.Key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible solution to your problem. 
Create and work with a Object that represents a week day and the weather peaks (High and Low Temps) for that particular date. Additionaly we add a property range that calculates the difference. Create a list and add all days to it. After that just iterate each day and return the range. See my code example below. Open VS, create new Console App and paste example.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<WeatherDay> weatherDays = new List<WeatherDay>();

        //add day of week and temp
        weatherDays.Add(new WeatherDay(1, 84, 65));
        weatherDays.Add(new WeatherDay(2, 86, 66));
        weatherDays.Add(new WeatherDay(3, 81, 71));
        weatherDays.Add(new WeatherDay(4, 82, 60));
        weatherDays.Add(new WeatherDay(5, 82, 64));
        weatherDays.Add(new WeatherDay(6, 83, 69));
        weatherDays.Add(new WeatherDay(7, 84, 70));

        weatherDays.ForEach(wetherDay => {
            Console.WriteLine("The range for Day {0} of the week was {1}", wetherDay.Day, wetherDay.Range);
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class WeatherDay
{
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int HighTemp { get; set; }
    public int LowTemp { get; set; }

    public WeatherDay(int day, int highTemp, int lowTemp)
    {
        this.Day = day;
        this.HighTemp = highTemp;
        this.LowTemp = lowTemp;
    }
    public int Range { get { return HighTemp - LowTemp; } }
}
```

I hope this can help you further! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid the loop happening, but you can avoid coding it by learning some Linq:

```
public Dictionary<int,int> TempRange 
{ 
  get { 
      return LowTemps.ToDictionary(l => l.Key, l => HighTemps[l.Key] - l.Value); 
      }
}
```

but I agree with all @Zyo's points.